# summing up values in an array

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

How do I sum up the values for my array? Here's the output if I trace my array (I couldn't find the actionscript equivalent of PHP's print_r function):

```
for(var k:int=0; k<tempAC.length; k++){
    trace(tempAC[k].name);
    trace(tempAC[k].value);
    trace('-----------');
}

__OUTPUT__

Bob
3
-----------
Mary
5
-----------
Bob
12
-----------
Mary
1
```

How do I construct an array that would sum up Bob & Mary's respective values?
ie the Output would be:

```
Bob
15
------------
Mary
6
------------
```

I've got (where I try += to sum the values):

```
for(var k:int=0; k<tempAC.length; k++){
   newAC['name']=tempAC[k].name;
   newAC['value']+=tempAC[k].value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var tempAC:Array = [
    {name: "Bob", value: 3},
    {name: "Mary", value: 5},
    {name: "Bob", value: 12},
    {name: "Mary", value: 1}
];

/**
 * Combines values in objects that have identical names
 * @param ar The array to assess
 */
function combine(ar:Array):Array
{
    var hold:Array = [];
    var back:Array = [];

    var i:Object;
    for each(i in ar)
    {
        if(!hold[i.name]) hold[i.name] = i.value;
        else hold[i.name] += i.value;
    }

    var j:String;
    for(j in hold)
    {
        back.push({name: j, value: hold[j]});
    }

    return back;
}


var list:Array = combine(tempAC);

var i:Object;
for each(i in list)
{
    trace(i.name + ": " + i.value);
}

Output:
Bob: 15
Mary: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var k:int=0; k<tempAC.length; k++){
   newAC[tempAC[k].name]+=tempAC[k].value;
}
```

That way you sum each name separately, regardless how many names u have there.

To see output:
(what ever is your print method, I'll call it `echo`)

```
echo newAC['THE NAME YOU WANT'];
```

b.t.w I have no idea about Flash, but the concept is good, and the syntax (except the `echo`) is also good.

Comment: thanks but I need the keys on the new AC to be "name" and "value" so that I can use the data in a chart

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong but I get the original values, not the summations

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at creating an [Associative Array with a String Key](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=10_Lists_of_data_4.html). Read the article and it should get you started.